# Побитовое чтение и запись видеофайла *.ts

Tags: c++, файлы, видео, запись

В дипломном C++ проекте необходимо работать с видеофайлами транспортного потока MPEG (формат [*.ts](http://www.online-convert.com/ru/file-format/ts)), а именно: необходимо получать из файла блоки бит достаточно большой длины (не более 53840 бит в блоке), а после определенных манипуляций записывать новые блоки в новый *.ts файл. Я хочу обойтись без специальных библиотек типа OpenCV.

Уже понял, что работа с нетекстовыми файлами не кардинально отличается от работы с текстовыми, однако неясными остались пара вопросов:

- Как следует организовать открытие файла?
- Как следует организовать чтение/запись данных?

Comment: 53840 бит - это всего лишь 6,7кб.. Интересно, как это может являться "достаточно большой длиной".

Comment: Здесь Вам следует обратиться к описанию формата. В нём Вы найдёте ответы на большинство Ваших вопросов. Однако, ИМХО, смысла отказываться от готовых библиотек, если задачу можно решить с их помощью, нет. Конечно, если речь не идёт о разработке своей специализированной библиотеки или академическом интересе.

Comment: @Streletz дело как раз в академическом интересе. На текущий момент проект содержит только стандартные библиотеки, и не хотелось бы привлекать пушку для отстрела воробья. Меня интересует принцип считывания _какого-нибудь_ нетекстового файла: на месте *.ts может оказаться *.avi или *.bmp

Comment: Принцип, как правило, один. Побайтовое чтение. Однако нужно понимать, что данные в файле определённого формата также хранятся **строго** определённым образом. Поэтому без описания формата, корректная работа с таким файлом вряд ли получится. Скорее наоборот.

Comment: Добавлю. При отказе от стандартных библиотек Вам придётся реализовать все необходимые операции с ним самостоятельно. Поэтому неизвестно, что лучше "привлечь"пушку" или "изобретать велосипед". В прочем, так как проект основан на академическом интересе, принципом технологической целесообразности в данном конкретном случае можно в некоторой степени пренебречь.

Comment: @Streletz работа заключается в моделировании помехоустойчивых кодов. Иными словами: я считываю файл блоками, добавляю к ним проверочные символы, прогоняю через модель канала, исправляю ошибки, собираю новый файл (в идеальном случае -- из тех же блоков, на которые разбирал). Т.е. полагаю, что мне совершенно неважно, как устроен этот файл внутри.

Comment: В новый файл можно собрать любой набор двоичных данных. Это дело не хитрое. Только результат "сборки" может быть, скажем так, разным. В прочем, смотрите сами...